# Hibernate HQL Searching in Set

Tags: hibernate, oop, hql

I have an object "Staff" which contains a set of "Student" objects which the staff member teaches.

I need to return a list of Staff objects which contain a particular student object in their set.

Attempt:

```
select s from Staff s where ????
```

How can this be done using HQL?

Comment: Please paste your classes.

Comment: Staff has Set<Student> .